# ¿Cómo podría mandar una función a través de ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Holaa, estoy intentando obtener un id a través de una función que se actualiza cada x segundos, la cosa que al ser una función de javascript adquiere el primer value y posteriormente se envía por ajax, es decir, envía un valor nulo. Por lo que para eso pensé insertar un interval y que actualice cada 1s el value, el problema es que al hacer eso, AJAX deja de reconocer la variable como tal y arroja un error en la consola. Espero haberme explicado, dejo aquí el code:

***UPDATE: CON LA NUEVA EDICIÓN DE CÓDIGO ME ENVÍA UN DATO QUE NO CORRESPONDE AL QUERIDO.***

```
    const xdnt = window.setInterval(function () {
        localStorage.getItem('us');
    }, 1000);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./assets/php/app.php",
  data: {
    dust: dust,
    ip_f: localStorage.getItem("ip_f"),
    b: localStorage.getItem("time"),
    type_of_user: type_of_user,
    totem: localStorage.getItem("totem"),
    tassy: tassy,
    cumm: cumm,
    fp_p_g: xdnt
  }
}).done(function(msg) {
  console.log("Los datos que se recibieron: " + msg);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras haber probado bastantes cosas he pensado que se podría hacer a través de un `setTimeout`, ya que eso retrasaría la ejecución del code y se ejecutaría justo después de haberse interpuesto ese valor.

Dejo aquí el código por si alguno le sirve.

```
setTimeout("const deitah = localStorage.getItem('us')", 2000);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./assets/php/app.php",
  data: {
    dust: dust,
    ip_f: localStorage.getItem("ip_f"),
    b: localStorage.getItem("time"),
    type_of_user: type_of_user,
    totem: localStorage.getItem("totem"),
    tassy: tassy,
    cumm: cumm,
    fp_p_g: deitah
  }
}).done(function(msg) {
  console.log("Los datos que se recibieron: " + msg);
});
```